# ColdFusion Captcha Handler Mapping in IIS7

Tags: iis, coldfusion, mapping, captcha, wildcard

What is the handler mapping needed in IIS 7.x to produce CAPTCHA images?  The only one that works seems to be the wildcard, which is ridiculous from a security point of view.  In tightening the security of ColdFusion according to the lock-down guide at http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/whitepapers/pdf/91025512_cf9_ lockdownguide_wp_ue.pdf, they recommend to remove this wildcard mapping, but that seems to break captcha.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the setting is but you could try: Save the image to a web-accessible folder using the destination attribute. Use img src to display it. Add a scheduled task that every hour/day would delete images older than that time period.